# detecting closing tab or browser script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on the asp.net mvc application. i came across scenario where i need to detect whether user has clicked on closing tab or browser. i got the script below but this script is also called when user submit the form. e.g. on submit button. i need script that can run when closing tab or browser.

**Script**

```
(function($) {
    var refreshKeyPressed = false;
    var modifierPressed = false;
    var f5key = 116;
    var rkey = 82;
    var modkey = [17, 224, 91, 93];

    // Check for refresh keys
    $(document).bind('keydown',function(evt) {
        // Check for refresh
        if (evt.which == f5key || window.modifierPressed && evt.which == rkey) {
            refreshKeyPressed = true;
        }

        // Check for modifier
        if (modkey.indexOf(evt.which) >= 0) {
            modifierPressed = true;
        }
    });

    // Check for refresh keys
    $(document).bind('keyup', function(evt) {
        // Check undo keys
        if (evt.which == f5key || evt.which == rkey) {
            refreshKeyPressed = false;
        }

        // Check for modifier
        if (modkey.indexOf(evt.which) >= 0) {
            modifierPressed = false;
        }
    });

    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(event) {
        var message = "not refreshed";

        if (refreshKeyPressed) {
            message = "refreshed";
        }

        event.returnValue = message;
        return message;
    });
}(jQuery));
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
    return "If you close the window, your application with still be running. If you wish to stop the application, click 'cancel' and "
});
```

Comment: which version of `jQuery` you are using?

Comment: i am using jquery-1.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `onbeforeunload`.

> An event that fires when a window is about to unload its resources. The document is still visible and the event is still cancelable.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

**EDIT**

Use `on` instead of `bind`. You are using `bind` to attach events on elements.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {
    return "If you close the window, your application with still be running. If you wish to stop the application, click 'cancel' and "
});
```

**EDIT-2**

The `submit` button will submit the form and will refresh the page unless you have prevented this action. If you want to prevent this from happening you should either `preventDefault` submit of the form or add a check on the `unload` event.

```
var submitting = false;
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    submitting = true;
    ...

});


$(window).bind('beforeunload', function (e) {
    if (!submitting) {
        return "If you close the window, your application with still be running. If you wish to stop the application, click 'cancel' and "
    }
    return false; // Prevent the alert box
});
```

Comment: Tried the above mention code but it never fires. i tried it on chrome.

Comment: @HammadBukhari Works for me. You have to put this in the code outside of any function

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            return 'Dialog text here.';
        };
    </script>. .... does not work

Comment: @HammadBukhari It is working for me, is your code has effect on this

Comment: i am using asp.net mvc4.. when i put this code inside layout.cshtml then it works..

Comment: but putting this code in layout is not my requirement. i dont know why its not working in other pages?

Comment: i am using jquery-1.9.1

Comment: working but same issue. this script runs even when i clicked on submit button of this page.

Comment: Will it be possible not to show the message box . instead i just want to call controller function.

Comment: @HammadBukhari Updated answer. added `return false;` to prevent the event.